# Настройка CORS на NGINX

Tags: nginx, cors

У меня есть HTTP сервер на flask, он запущен на сервере и слушает порт 6000.
Фронт у меня написан на Vue JS, в качестве WEB-сервера использую NGINX. У меня возникла проблема с CORS, NGINX не дает доступ к бэк серверу:
[image: Ответ NGINX при попытке запроса на proxy сервер]

[image: Ответ NGINX при попытке запроса на proxy сервер]

Настройка NGINX proxy сервера:
[image: Настройка NGINX сервера]

Comment: Зачем CORS? конфигурите `proxy_pass` у nginx на flask, и ходите с фронта на nginx. У вас каждый за что отвечает?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, о чем идёт речь, можно ли подробнее описать или скинуть ссылку? У меня есть сервер на фласке, у меня он просто обрабатывает гет пост запросы и работает с бд и есть фронт на вью js с которого я посылаю запросы.

Comment: a nginx в этой схеме что делает?

Comment: Он выполняет роль web сервера, который выдаёт исходный код сайта клиенту и обрабатывает запросы на получения данных с бд от фронта, передавая их по прокси фласку.

Comment: То есть фронт всегда ходит только на 6001-nginx. Тогда CORS не должен ругаться.

Comment: Фронт ходит на 443 за исходниками и на 6001 за данными

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом случае лучше сделать так, чтобы фронт ходил только на nginx, на один и тот же порт за исходниками и за данными.

Решение о пробрасывании на flask можно принимать на основе:

- пути -- все `/api/` пробросить
- метода -- все `POST` пробросить
- кастомного `x-*` заголовка -- фронт сам говорит, что надо пробросить
- заголовка `Accept` -- тип контента, SSE
- `try_files` -- пробросить если нет статического файла

Comment: Большое спасибо, вопрос решен!